# unable to locate svn directory physically on windows server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have just successfully installed the subversion in windows server 2008
i can checkout the directory from my client machine svn://ip/test
but i am unable to locate test directory on server.

Repository in F:\SvnRepository and conf folder in F:\SvnRepository\conf and binaries are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion
Created directory by executing the command `svn mkdir svn://localhost/test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The svn repository cannot be used like a working copy. Simply check out the repository to a working copy somewhere (with `svn checkout` - you already did that at least once).

Also, note that using `svn mkdir` with a URL is an unusual command. Typically, you create the local changes (including new directories) in your working copy (on the client) and then [*commit*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html) them.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It means if I rdc on server I can not view or access my project/svn directories. the only way to to get my source is to checkout from client machine. is that right?

Comment: @KamranAkhter Well, you can of course also create as many checkouts as you want on the server machine or anywhere else if you want to see the contents of the repository on another system.

Comment: installing tortoise svn on server could help?

Comment: @KamranAkhter TortoiseSvn is a graphical interface on svn. Sure, you could install it and use it to create a working copy wherever you like. However, the command-line client is less light-weight and therefore more suitable for a server. You can also use any other computer at hand to create a checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svn mkdir  but it's a bit awkward methods. I use this method only when i really need create a structure online because i don't want to checkout everything. For example:

```
svn mkdir http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/newclientcode/
svn mkdir http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/newclientcode/web/
svn mkdir http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/newclientcode/web/trunk/
svn mkdir http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/newclientcode/web/branches/
svn mkdir http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/newclientcode/web/tags/
svn co http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/newclientcode/web/trunk/
```

and then start working with with the new checkedout trunk. Note too, that you only do that if you already got something in http://myserver:81/svn/CatalogRepo/ for example... if the repo is clean, just check it out locally, create your folders, publish the changes ALL AT ONCE and then delete and checkout again the trunk this time.

The creation of directories directly on the  server forces you to create a revision everytime you send a command while checking out a directory and doing everything locally allows you to do one big commit, it's much better that way!

Comment: but my question is how can i access the physical files on server, I can not view where is my test directory which i had created through svn mkdir svn://localhost/test (absolute path on server)

Comment: The svn server stores it's files into a complex set of folders and files called the SVN database... The way to work with SVN is not to push your files into SVN to server them to the web. Instead you use it to track your different changes in your DEV environment and push them into your SVN server. THEN, when you are ready to go into PRODUCTION, you checkout/update a copy of the code on the production server. This way, there are no files or folders missing and all changes are correctly ported to the production environment.

Comment: The important aspect is that it is only one part of successful development strategy. You still need to organize your SQL files and database to not forget changes pushed into it and still run SQL change files on your production environment

Comment: The only thing you need to do is use "SVN CO <URL>" to checkout a copy locally on your computer or on the production server and then "SVN CI" or "SVN UP" to update and commit your changes back to SVN. Hope this helped...

Comment: Thanks for reply Mathieu. suppose if i need to take backup of a source from server in usb and server is not on the network how can i do that? my prob is to copy files from server directly (assuming the condition) however i can checkout from my computer if server is on network

Comment: If you have no network access from the server to your SVN server, then you need to (everytime) EXPORT a copy to another folder and push those files online. But pushing and exported copy doesn't remove the files you renamed or deleted. You're much better off with a public secure SVN server and checkout on your server.

Comment: Installing Tortoise svn can help me in this regard, there is option to create repository here but can i checkout directories in the same way as i did svn://ip/test with subverion

Comment: Tortoise SVN is a visual SVN gadget. It can do all if not more than the command line SVN can do. If you want to learn how to use SVN and TortoiseSVN you might want to check for online tutorials or online courses about SVN usage in a business or in a development process.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the "svnadmin create " normally it is being created at your

system32 folder [ C:\Windows\System32 ].